# Did it make sense for the Roman Empire to build a great wall?

Tags: roman-empire

Both Roman Empire and Han dynasty had to defend their northern boarders against powerful enemies, so both of them had the motivation to build a great wall along their northern boarders.

Roman Empire and Han dynasty had roughly the same size and population. If the Chinese had enough resources and manpower to build a great wall, then the Romans should also have.

Why didn't Roman Empire build a great wall, as the Qin dynasty and Han dynasty did? Did it not make sense for them?

Comment: When it made sense (geographically & politically), they did. See: [Antonine Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonine_Wall) & [Hadrian's Wall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadrian%27s_Wall).

Comment: As for why walls didn't always make sense, my impression (and this pure speculation on my part) is that the very concept of a great wall along their boarders would have been completely at odds with their view of themselves as natural conquerors. Romans didn't really think of their as having a boarder; instead, they would have called it the frontier which was in a constant state of expansion. By the time you finish the wall, the other side might well have already been incorporated into Rome. Even Hadrian's Wall was really kind of a last resort

Comment: @DavidH I think you meant "border" rather than "boarder". :)

Comment: They actually had a wall in central Europe, with watchtowers, checkpoints and the like. But it was of wood rather than of stone. This is because France and Germany had a lot of forests but little stone available. Good question, I vote to reopen.

Comment: Also, with exceptions, the borders of the Empire ran over the Rin and Danube rivers, which are more formidable obstacles than most walls.

Comment: I made the question more objective by asking if it made sense to build a wall in the first place, and vote to re=open.

Comment: Also, the northern neighbours of Rome were not horsemen / mounted archers. Mongols were very strong enemies on an open plan, but even a low wall like the japanese wall (about 1 m high) could seriously hinder their movement. Against stronger stone fortifications, they had no effective weapons. The difference was not that steep agains infantry who can perform a siege.

Comment: Well, the Romans built a type of Great Wall nearly 2000 years ago, called, "Hadrian's Wall" in Northern "Britannia"-(present-day Northern England). Hadrian's Wall was built in the most Northern frontier of The Roman Empire. I say, "frontier", because Northern England, as well as Southern Scotland, during the 100's AD/CE, was a wildly pastoral frontier zone largely populated by, "barbarians". The Romans viewed the Ancient Scots as wildly uncivilized "barbarians", who needed to be literally walled off, in order to better protect the peripheral zone of the Empire-(i.e. Celtic Northern Britannia).